# Display multiple CSV columns that have space on one line

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file with first and last names. The headers are "**First Name**" and "**Last Name**". I can get it to display, but it puts the first and last name on separate lines.

**Question:** How can I get the output to display both together on one line in Powershell.

This PowerShell separates the values on separate lines:

```
 Import-Csv -Path C:\file1.csv | foreach {echo $_.'First Name’ $_.'Last Name’}
```

Comment: Use "write-host" instead of "echo".

Answer (score 1):

Using the [$( ) SubExpression operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) in a nested fashion it's possible to concatenate multiple subexpression results and return those as a group within another subexpression returning the output as desired (i.e. `"$($(mutlivalue1) $(multivalue2))" == "val1 val2"`).

### PowerShell

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\file1.csv" | %{"$($_."First Name") $($_."Last Name")"};
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- ### [`Operators $( ) @( ) :: &`](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)

  > **$( ) SubExpression operator.**
  >
  > Use a subexpression to return specific
  >   [properties](https://ss64.com/ps/get-member.html) of an object. Unlike
  >   simple parenthesis, a subexpression can contain multiple ; semicolon ;
  >   separated ; statements.
  >
  > The output of each statement contributes to the output of the
  >   subexpression. For a single result, it will return a scalar. For
  >   multiple results, it will return an array.
  >
  > Subexpressions allow you to
  >   evaluate and act on the results of an expression in a single line;
  >   with no need for an intermediate variable:

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\file1.csv | foreach {'{0} {1}' -f $_.'First Name’, $_.'Last Name’ | Write-host}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you multiple methods :

```
#method 0 : on one row by you can keep your columns (result are list of objects)
import-csv "C:\temp\yooo.txt" | select "First Name", "Last Name"

#method 1 : create new column in select (result are list of objects)
import-csv "C:\temp\yooo.txt" | select @{Name="Identity";Expression={"{0} {1}" -f $_."First Name", $_."Last Name"}}

#method 2 : create new column in loop (result are list of string)
import-csv "C:\temp\yooo.txt" | %{"{0} {1}" -f $_."First Name", $_."Last Name"}

#method 3 : create new object in loop (result are list of objects)
import-csv "C:\temp\yooo.txt" | %{

[pscustomobject]@{
FirstName=$_."First Name"
LastName=$_."Last Name"
}

}
```